# geoSPARQL distance produces empty results

Tags: sparql, distance, graphdb, geosparql

I try using the distance geoSPARQL function in graphDB and I don't get any result. Here's a test :

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX wgs84_pos: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>
PREFIX geoSparql: <http://www.ontotext.com/plugins/geosparql#>
PREFIX geosparql: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.opengis.net/ont/geosparql#>
PREFIX geof: <http://www.opengis.net/def/function/geosparql/>
PREFIX uom: <http://www.opengis.net/def/uom/OGC/1.0/>
SELECT ?d
WHERE {
  BIND(geof:distance 
   ("<http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/2154> POINT (420670.213757502 6227859.48099221)",
    "<http://www.opengis.net/def/crs/EPSG/0/2154> POINT(627006.586743735 6386592.47021308)",
    uom:meter) as ?d)
      }
```

Kind regards.

Answer (score 3):

Got it :)

uom:**meter** -> uom:**metre**